# Aiogram 3, как Получить целиком запрос от бота в json

Tags: python, json, aiogram-3.x

Други, прошу простить за столь **** вопрос, но быстро в лоб не смог найти ответ.

Как можно получить целиком ответ от бота телеграмм в виде json, используя **aiogram 3.xx**.

В частности, искал, способ получить текущий **update_id** в процедуре **cmd_start**, но не смог найти как это сделать методами aiogram, хотел спарсить в лоб из json ответа.

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from aiogram.types import Message
import asyncio
from aiogram.methods import DeleteWebhook

bot = Bot('12345678:AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHh', parse_mode="HTML")
dp = Dispatcher()

@dp.message()
async def cmd_start(message: Message, bot: Bot):
    if message.text == 'exit':
        print("exit - ", str(message.chat.username))
        await message.answer("exiting...")
        await dp.stop_polling()
        await bot.session.close()

    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"Hello! {message.from_user.first_name} {message.from_user.id}!")
    await message.answer("<tg-spoiler>test spoiler!</tg-spoiler>")
    await message.reply("test reply")


# Запуск процесса поллинга новых апдейтов
async def main():
    await bot(DeleteWebhook(drop_pending_updates=True))  # отключаем обновления
    await dp.start_polling(bot, skip_updates=True)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать метод `model_dump_json()`

Например:

```
@dp.message()
async def cmd_start(message: Message, bot: Bot):
    if message.text == 'exit':
        print("exit - ", str(message.chat.username))
        print (message.model_dump_json())               #тут
        await message.answer("exiting...")
        await dp.stop_polling()
        await bot.session.close()
```

Comment: спасибо, этот метод работает. Но получаем  только то, что прилетает на событие .message. А как отслеживать  все события которые получем по GetUpdate, если бы это делалось через запрос руками: **https://api.telegram.org/bot{-Variable.bot_token-}/getUpdates?offset={-Variable.last_update_id-}**   В случае с aiogram этот запрос делает диспетчер как я понимаю, с параметрами прописанными в bot.  Хочу увидеть ответ по этому запросу целиком,, каким либо способом,  если это возможно конечно.

Comment: @deza ну так на update вешайте же. Я ж для примера message привел. Да и у вас в коде он был

Comment: @deza, хотя нет, так просто не получится... Наверное через миддлварь, а потом передать в хендлер... А собственно, какая задача-то стоит?

Comment: задача, адаптирую бота, коорый делался в связке ZennoPoster+C# ,  на бота в питоне. Всех тонкостей AIogram не знаю, потихоньку изучаю. Ранее - разбирался пакет с ответом json вручную. И далее работали обработчики событий. Здесь не знаю как просмотреть все события пришедшие в бот, для каждого надо описать декоратор сначала... Хотелось бы видеть, что надо обрабатывать, а что можно пока проигнорировать.

Answer (score 0):

PS а до самого ***update_id*** обновления, так и не докопался :(
Покурив интернет, и используя подсказку уважаемого **[@CausonQ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/557751/causonq)**
наваял такую функцию -  ***get_data_message***, которая конвертит json 2 dict. возможно кому-то пригодится

```
from aiogram.methods import DeleteWebhook
import asyncio
import logging
from aiogram.types import Message
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, F
from typing import Dict
# BOT_TOKEN='' # - заменить значение переменной на свое, а этот импорт удалить: from core.settings import BOT_TOKEN
from core.settings import BOT_TOKEN
bot = Bot(BOT_TOKEN,
          parse_mode="HTML")
dp = Dispatcher()
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                    format="%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
                    "(%(filename)s:%(lineno)d - %(message)s)")

# функция для конвертации json в словарь, key - value
async def get_data_message(data_message: Dict, prefix: str = '', sep: str = '.'):
    correct_dict = {}
    for key, value in data_message.items():
        if value != None:
            if isinstance(value, Dict):
                correct_dict.update(await get_data_message(data_message=value, prefix=f'{prefix}{key}{sep}'))
            else:
                correct_dict[f'{prefix}{key}'] = value
    return correct_dict


@dp.message(F.text)
async def get_text(message: Message):
    await message.answer(message.text) # эхо сообщение
    for key, value in (await get_data_message(data_message=message.model_dump())).items(): # выводим json на экран
        print(f'{key} - {value}')
    


async def main():

    # dp.message.register(get_text, F.text)
    await bot(DeleteWebhook(drop_pending_updates=True))  # отключаем обновления
    try:
        await dp.start_polling(bot, skip_updates=True)
    finally:
        await bot.session.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```